# inherited classic asp site on windows server 2008 r2 getting connection_dropped errors

Tags: iis-7, asp

Trying to debug a problem with a classic asp app that I have to get running on some internal servers.

Running IIS 7.5 on Server 2008 R2, I'm getting most pages working OK, but one page (so far) that is supposed to lookup a file location in the DB, then stream that file from the file system to the client is not working.  It's immediately (15ms) losing the connection; the server HTTPERR logs report the request coming in and say dropped_connection.

It happens on all the files that use that download url, and I've verified that the database has the correct paths and the files are located in the right paths.  I've also checked permissions, and the app pool identity has Full Control permissions on the file location.

NOt really sure what else to check, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising:

FIX: Incorrect response or connection fails in IIS 7.5 after an ISAPI filter registers for SF_NOTIFY_SEND_RAW_DATA event notifications

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2467528

Comment: No, doesn't match that profile.  I ended up fixing it by changing some of the source code, though I'm curious whether it was a windows patch or something that broke the original.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the developer of the original code (no idea who that was or when) wasn't explicitly flushing the request.  I don't know if that's something that wasn't needed when he developed it or what, but I ended up adding:

```
Request.Flush
```

to the .asp file that he was using to stream the files out, and that fixed it.